# userprofile matching query does not exist django facebook error

Tags: django, django-models, django-facebook

I am getting the following error after integrating

DoesNotExist at /facebook/connect/
UserProfile matching query does not exist.

**Here is my models.py**

```
from django.db import models


from django_facebook.models import FacebookProfileModel

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(FacebookProfileModel):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)


from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)

def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):


    if created: 

        profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

**ALSO IN MY SETTINGS**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'kk.UserProfile'
```

PLEASE HELP!

**EDIT** 
**EDIT**     My traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/facebook/connect/?facebook_login=1

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django_facebook',
 'kk')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook-4.0.8-py2.7.egg/django_facebook/utils.py" in wrapper
  358.         response = f(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook-4.0.8-py2.7.egg/django_facebook/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  89.                 get_persistent_graph(request, redirect_uri=current_uri)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook-4.0.8-py2.7.egg/django_facebook/api.py" in get_persistent_graph
  61.         graph = get_facebook_graph(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_facebook-4.0.8-py2.7.egg/django_facebook/api.py" in get_facebook_graph
  181.                 profile = request.user.get_profile()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in get_profile
  400.                                    self._state.db).get(user__id__exact=self.id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  366.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /facebook/connect/
Exception Value: UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1):

Either your create_profile signal isn't being fired (is the signal file being imported from somewhere in django machinery?)

Or you have existing users who have yet to run through your new create_profile signal handler.

Posting the traceback always helps.

Comment: i have added the traceback.Please look into this.

Comment: Sounds like either of the two solutions I posted. Make sure all users have a UserProfile. If you installed this solution mid-way, only users created from that point on will have profiles auto created. OR, your signal isn't firing and you need to fix that first. Go into the django shell, and type in `User.objects.filter(userprofile__isnull=True).count()` <-- if this is more than 0, you need to iterate through them and call save() so your signal handler populates the defaults